# How to debug android service written by shell script?

Tags: android, shell

I just write a shell script and registered it as Android service.
It will do something via check some property like follows.
How can I debug it? I cannot sure it runs as my aspect or not.

I used "echo" but I cannot see the message in kmsg or logcat.

Thanks

--

```
if [ ".$prop" == ".0" ]; then
    echo "prop == 0 BEGIN"
    # Do something
    echo "prop == 0 END"
elif [ ".prop" == ".1" ]; then
    echo "prop == 1 BEGIN"
    # Do something
    echo "prop == 1 END"
fi
```

Comment: how about do some actions in the block, e.g. writing log?

Comment: Thanks for your suggest! I used "echo" but no effect.

Comment: this is an Android Service, you can't expect it "echoes" something out...

Comment: I know, so I ask how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
It will write log to Logcat and with TAG and priority.

```
if [ ".$prop" == ".0" ]; then
    /system/bin/log -t ${TAG} -p i "prop == 0 BEGIN"
    # Do something
    /system/bin/log -t ${TAG} -p i "prop == 0 END"
elif [ ".prop" == ".1" ]; then
    /system/bin/log -t ${TAG} -p i "prop == 1 BEGIN"
    # Do something
    /system/bin/log -t ${TAG} -p i "prop == 1 END"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Like any other shell script, you can redirect the output to a file:

```
if [ ".$prop" == ".0" ]; then
    echo "prop == 0 BEGIN" >> /sdcard/test.txt
    # Do something
    echo "prop == 0 END" >> /sdcard/test.txt
elif [ ".prop" == ".1" ]; then
    echo "prop == 1 BEGIN" >> /sdcard/test.txt
    # Do something
    echo "prop == 1 END" >> /sdcard/test.txt
fi
```

Try this.